# Catching specific error message from a BASE R function

Tags: r, function

I want to make an `if` statement whenever the `reshape` function in BASE R throws the following specific error: `failed to guess time-varying variables from their names`.

How can I catch this specific error from `reshape` and make: `if(that specific error came up) return(NA)`?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
input <- data.frame(id = 1:3, school = LETTERS[1:3], read_2018 =20:22, read_2019 = 30:32)

out <- reshape(input, dir = 'long', idvar = c("id", "school"), varying = c('read_2018', 'read_2019'))

# if(`out` gives that specific error) return(NA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `tryCatch`, capture the error message and return `NA` if that specific error message occurs.

```
out <- tryCatch({reshape(input, dir = 'long', idvar = c("id", "school"), 
                 varying = c('read_2018', 'read_2019'))}, 
     error = function(e) {
       if(as.character(e) == "Error in guess(varying): failed to guess time-varying variables from their names\n") NA 
       else e
})
out
#[1] NA
```